# How to visually indent continuation lines of Org property values to align with the column specified in org-property-format?

Tags: org-mode, font-lock, text-properties, visual-line-mode

Long property values in Org mode property drawers are by default not visually indented in `visual-line-mode` so as to align with the start column of the property values (as defined in `org-property-format`). Instead they just continue at the beginning of the next line, the same column where the property keywords start.

My idea is to achieve the desired behavior by setting the wrap-prefix text property of the property values using font locking. [adaptive-wrap.el](https://github.com/emacsmirror/adaptive-wrap/blob/master/adaptive-wrap.el) provides some useful related code, but I don't think I understand font locking well enough to efficiently implement this.

Comment: AFAIK, the value of a property starts after the closing colon of the name (white space at the beginning of the value does not count) and continues to the end of the line. There is no continuation mechanism. At least the Org manual says: "Each property is specified on **a single line**, with the key—surrounded by colons—first, and the value after it." (emphasis added). So I don't understand what continuation lines you are talking about.

Comment: Thanks. I edited my question to clarify that I am talking about the continuation of long lines created by `visual-line-mode`; that is, the part of a long logical line that is displayed on a new visual line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to come up with some working code, but I'm not sure whether this is the best way:

```lisp
(defun my-org-property-value-wrap (limit)
  "Ensure that property values wrap properly.
This sets the wrap-prefix of property values so that the continuation
of long values after a line wrap aligns with the start of the value.
`org-property-format' is used for this. Nothing is done when
`truncate-lines' is non-nil."
  (unless truncate-lines
    (let ((cols (string-search "%s" (format org-property-format "" "%s"))))
      (while (re-search-forward org-property-re limit t)
        (put-text-property
         (match-beginning 3)
         (match-end 3)
         'wrap-prefix
         (concat (get-text-property (pos-bol) 'wrap-prefix)
                 (propertize (make-string cols ? )
                             'face 'org-special-keyword)))))))

(font-lock-add-keywords 'org-mode '(my-org-property-value-wrap))
```